# What do if there are multiple answers that are equally great?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a couple questions out now that each have multiple brilliant responses. I'm conflicted on which answer to select as the "accepted answer".

What should an OP do for questions like these? I don't want to imply that one answer is necessarily better than another but I also don't want to leave around a bunch of questions without an accepted answer.

Thoughts?

-M

Answer (score 4):

Let the community decide.

Leave the questions be for a bit, and then accept the answer that was voted up the most by the community.

Answer (score 2):

I usually wait for a bit and see which one starts pulling ahead in votes. However, sometimes this doesn't happen, and the two answers get the same number of up votes. In situations like this, I'd go with the answer that you actually use to solve your problem. If they're basically the same answer, but each one has some unique points to it, then I go with the first one posted. (See this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-soffit-vents-vs-roof-vents) as an example. At the time I accepted it, each answer had 2 votes, and I'm pretty my choice of which to accept skewed the votes afterwards.)